# Uninitialized variable inside the try/catch with unhandled exception

Tags: java, variables, exception, initialization, try-catch

I have a variable to initialize that is coming from a class with exception.

So if I do something like ConfigurationProvider reader = configurationReader.configurationProvider(), the .configurationProvider() part shows the red line telling the exception is unhandled in IntelliJ.

So I tried catching it inside the try/catch block like the following:

```
    private String getConfigValue(ConfigurationProviderConfiguration configurationReader, String configName) {
        String value = null;
        ConfigurationProvider reader;
        try {
             reader = configurationReader.configurationProvider();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Properties config = reader.getConfiguration(configName); //Now, there is a red line under reader saying the variable might not have been initialized
        if (config == null) {
            LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
        }else{
            value = config.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Now as you can see in the comment, there is a red line under reader saying the variable is not initialized. I understand why the compiler is complaining since it may skip the try and go to the catch block. I would try deleting catch block but I also can't do that since I have to handle the exception. What can I do in this case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Initialize it: `ConfigurationProvider reader = null;`

Comment: Put your code that uses the reader in the try block too.

Comment: @CardinalSystem Which then produces a null pointer exception when the execution gets to that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a path of execution where `reader` is not initialized -- if an exception is thrown and caught.  It looks like you shouldn't even try to use `reader` if an exception was thrown attempting to initialize it.

Only if an exception wasn't thrown should you use it and attempt to return a value.  Place all the code following the `catch` block into the `try` block following the initialization.

```
try {
    reader = configurationReader.configurationProvider();

    Properties config = reader.getConfiguration(configName);
    if (config == null) {
        LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
    } else {
        value = config.getValue();
        if (value == null) {
            LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
        }
    }
    return value;
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now the compiler will complain that not all paths return a value, which is true in this case when the exception is thrown.  Either re-throw the exception or return something to indicate that the returned value was invalid.  Re-throwing the exception will also require a `throws` clause on your method.

```
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
    // OR
    return null;
}
```

Comment: "Now the compiler will complain that not all paths return a value" - you could move the `return value;` line outside of the try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Move the rest of your code inside the same exception handler:

```
private String getConfigValue(ConfigurationProviderConfiguration configurationReader, String configName) {
    String value = null;
    ConfigurationProvider reader;
    try {
        reader = configurationReader.configurationProvider();

        Properties config = reader.getConfiguration(configName);
        if (config == null) {
            LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
        }else{
            value = config.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, yeah I'm not sure who down voted your post. I upvoted it yesterday to make it fair :)